# Adding two classes with same name to multiple xcodeproject under same workspace

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am new to iOS development. Unlike android i don't have any packages in iOS. My requirement is that I want to add same class(class name) in multiple packages. In android I can create a package and in the package I can add a class and in another package I can add class with same name. But in iOS if I add a class which is already present in a project it gives an error stating "invalid-redeclaration of class".How can I add multiple classes with same name in iOS Project?

Comment: If you have multiple targets in your project then you can have multiple files declaring the same class name as long as you only add one of those files to a given target The file properties inspector on the right lets you select the target(s) for a given file. If you only have one target in your project then you can only declare the class once

Comment: Thanks Paulw. I have  one xcworkspace.proj and under this workspace I have imported two different xcodeproj file which generate .lib files that linked to same workspace. both lib file have same  file names . but it is giving redeclaration  of file error. Do I have to rename all the files in second lib file or is there a way to add same file name in two .lib file as like in packages in android?

Comment: Isn't this basically a repost of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56298580/same-file-name-in-two-different-xcode-project-file-in-workspace)?

Comment: You set the file's target memberships in the file properties inspector, as I said.